# How to fix super slow EF/LINQ query executing multiple SQL statements

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, entity-framework

I have the following code, which is misbehaving:

```
TPM_USER user = UserManager.GetUser(context, UserId);
var tasks = (from t in user.TPM_TASK
             where t.STAGEID > 0 && t.STAGEID != 3 && t.TPM_PROJECTVERSION.STAGEID <= 10
             orderby t.DUEDATE, t.PROJECTID
             select t);
```

The first line, `UserManager.GetUser` just does a simple lookup in the database to get the correct `TPM_USER` record.  However, the second line causes all sorts of SQL chaos.

First off, it's executing two SQL statements here.  The first one grabs *every single row* in `TPM_TASK` which is linked to that user, which is sometimes tens of thousands of rows:

```
SELECT 
 -- Columns
 FROM  TPMDBO.TPM_USERTASKS "Extent1"
 INNER JOIN TPMDBO.TPM_TASK "Extent2" ON "Extent1".TASKID = "Extent2".TASKID
 WHERE "Extent1".USERID = :EntityKeyValue1
```

This query takes about 18 seconds on users with lots of tasks.  I would expect the WHERE clause to contain the STAGEID filters too, which would remove the majority of the rows.

Next, it seems to execute a new query for each `TPM_PROJECTVERSION` pair in the list above:

```
SELECT 
 -- Columns
 FROM TPMDBO.TPM_PROJECTVERSION "Extent1"
 WHERE ("Extent1".PROJECTID = :EntityKeyValue1) AND ("Extent1".VERSIONID = :EntityKeyValue2)
```

Even though this query is fast, it's executed several hundred times if the user has tasks in a whole bunch of projects.

The query I would like to generate would look something like:

```
SELECT 
 -- Columns
 FROM  TPMDBO.TPM_USERTASKS "Extent1"
 INNER JOIN TPMDBO.TPM_TASK "Extent2" ON "Extent1".TASKID = "Extent2".TASKID
 INNER JOIN TPMDBO.TPM_PROJECTVERSION "Extent3" ON "Extent2".PROJECTID = "Extent3".PROJECTID AND "Extent2".VERSIONID = "Extent3".VERSIONID
 WHERE "Extent1".USERID = 5 and "Extent2".STAGEID > 0 and "Extent2".STAGEID <> 3 and "Extent3".STAGEID <= 10
```

The query above would run in about 1 second.  Normally, I could specify that `JOIN` using the `Include` method.  However, this doesn't seem to work on properties.  In other words, I can't do:

```
from t in user.TPM_TASK.Include("TPM_PROJECTVERSION")
```

Is there any way to optimize this LINQ statement?  I'm using .NET4 and Oracle as the backend DB.

**Solution:**

This solution is based on Kirk's suggestions below, and works since `context.TPM_USERTASK` cannot be queried directly:

```
var tasks = (from t in context.TPM_TASK.Include("TPM_PROJECTVERSION")
             where t.TPM_USER.Any(y => y.USERID == UserId) &&
             t.STAGEID > 0 && t.STAGEID != 3 && t.TPM_PROJECTVERSION.STAGEID <= 10
             orderby t.DUEDATE, t.PROJECTID
             select t);
```

It *does* result in a nested `SELECT` rather than querying `TPM_USERTASK` directly, but it seems fairly efficient none-the-less.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you are pulling down a specific user, and then referencing the relationship `TPM_TASK`.  That it is pulling down every task attached to that user is exactly what it's supposed to be doing.  There's no ORM SQL translation when you're doing it this way.  You're getting a user, then getting all his tasks into memory, and then performing some client-side filtering.  This is all done using lazy-loading, so the SQL is going to be exceptionally inefficient as it can't batch anything up.

Instead, rewrite your query to go directly against `TPM_TASK` and filter against the user:

```
var tasks = (from t in context.TPM_TASK
         where t.USERID == user.UserId && t.STAGEID > 0 && t.STAGEID != 3 && t.TPM_PROJECTVERSION.STAGEID <= 10
         orderby t.DUEDATE, t.PROJECTID
         select t);
```

Note how we're checking `t.USERID == user.UserId`.  This produces the same effect as `user.TPM_TASK` but now all the heavy lifting is done by the database rather than in memory.

Comment: Unfortunately, this idea won't work.  `TPM_TASK` has no `USERID` property.  Users relate to tasks through the `TPM_USERTASK` table, which you can't query directly since it's used in a many-to-many relationship.  Maybe I'd be better off creating a view in the database or something?

Comment: You can certainly write the query to go against `TPM_USERTASK` as well.  I'm not sure how exactly your schema is set up, but something along the lines of `where t.TPM_TASK.Any(y => y.USERID == t.USER)` or just use `join` to bring in the many to many.  You definitely do not to be messing with views to achieve this.

Comment: Yup, thanks for your clear explanation!  That's pretty much what I figured was going on, but I'm still fairly new to EF.  Sometimes it's hard to see what gets magically turned into SQL and what gets handled manually by the runtime.  LINQ sure lets you shoot yourself in the foot easily.

Comment: @Mike, it does; with EF you can [disable the lazy loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967214/disable-lazy-loading-by-default-in-entity-framework-4).  That way you'd just get null reference exceptions instead of poor performance.  Since exceptions are obvious and poor performance can be subtle, this might be something worth considering.  If you disable lazy loading, you'll have to make sure to also learn about the `.Include` function (and ideally the [variant with lambdas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544756/using-include-in-entity-framework-4-with-lambda-expressions)).

Comment: Never knew you could use lambda expressions in the `Include` method, that's good to know!

Comment: @Mike only since 4.1; before that, `Include` takes dot-delimited navigation property strings