# Entity Framework - incorrectly doing 2 select statements instead of a join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orm, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have a fairly simple (code first) model:

**Employee**

```
[Table("vEmployee")] //note v - it's a view
public class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**EmployeeHolidayEntitlement**

```
[Table("tblEmployeeHolidayEntitlement")]
public class EmployeeHolidayEntitlement
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public decimal StandardEntitlement { get; set; }

    //.....omitted for brevity
}
```

**Note that EmployeeHolidayEntitlement is mapped to a table, and Employee is mapped to a view**

When building my context, I do:
(not sure if this is correct!)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
    .HasOptional(x => x.HolidayEntitlement)
    .WithRequired(x => x.Employee);
```

Now, when I query, like this:

```
var db = new ApiContext();
var result = db.Employees.ToList();
```

It's very slow.

If I look in SQL profiler, I can see that instead of one statement (joining vEmployee and tblEmployeeHolidayEntitlement) I get many statements executed (one per Employee record) - for example:

**First, it selects from `vEmployee`**

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[id] AS [EmployeeNumber], 
    [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
    [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
    FROM [dbo].[vEmployee] AS [Extent1]
```

**then one of these for each record returned**

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent1].[EmployeeNumber] AS [EmployeeNumber], 
    [Extent1].[StandardEntitlement] AS [StandardEntitlement]
    FROM [dbo].[tblEmployeeHolidayEntitlement] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[EmployeeNumber] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=175219
```

This doesn't seem right to me -

I would of thought it *should* be doing something more along the lines of a LEFT JOIN like

```
SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[vEmployee] employee
  LEFT JOIN
  [dbo].[tblEmployeeHolidayEntitlement employeeEntitlement
  ON
  employee.id = employeeEntitlement.employeenumber
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the Include method, like `db.Employees.Include(e => e.HolidayEntitlement).ToList()`.  If you don't and you access the property you'll trigger lazy loading.  That's what's happening to you.

[For more information check the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) on loading.  The short of it is that if it always joined your entire object graph it'd be unacceptably slow.

Comment: On the .Include, i can't specify a lambda, it wants a string?

Comment: @Alex You need need a `using` statement to access the lambda overload of `.Include`, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10079815/84206

Comment: Are you using EF6?  The lambda overload is newer, but the string overload does the same thing... see here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.include(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Got some reading to do on loading, but this has solved it, thank you :)