# Getting list of child entity nested several levels with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have entities that are nested in this order:

```
RootDomain
Company
CompaniesHouseRecord
CompanyOfficer
```

When given a RootDomain I want to create a list of all CompanyOfficers that have an email address but I am not sure how to do this.

Here Is my non-working attempt:

```
RootDomain rd = db.RootDomains.Find(123);
List<CompanyOfficer> col = rd.Companies.Where(x => x.CompaniesHouseRecords.Any(chr => chr.CompanyOfficers.Any(co => co.Email != null)))
                        .Select(x => x.CompaniesHouseRecords.Select(chr => chr.CompanyOfficers)).ToList();
```

I am obviously way off the mark here.  Can someone show me or point me to the correct method for dong this?

Comment: You might want to take a look at *Include()*. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5718935/1525840). Keep in mind that there are **two** different versions. The old one when you refer to the subfield by string and the new one where you use lambda expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
RootDomain rd = db.RootDomains.Find(123);
List<CompanyOfficer> col = rd.Companies
  .SelectMany(c => c.CompaniesHouseRecords)
  .SelectMany(c => c.CompanyOfficers)
  .Where(o => null != o.Email).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone answered before me, but I can show something different, which can be more convenient for someone who is used to DB requests.

Using LINQ, you can do this type of request:

```
var officersWithEmail = from company in rd.Companies
                        from companiesHouseRecord in company.CompaniesHouseRecords
                        from companyOfficer in companiesHouseRecord.CompanyOfficers
                        where (companyOfficer.Email != null)
                        select companyOfficer;
```

Some people will find it more readable.

If you want to obtain a List<> as output, just use .ToList on the query.